# Sending an email w/ attachment on AppEngine (BlobInfo)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

I just uploaded this on AppEngine - trying to send an email with an attachment (blobinfo). This returns a blank page - no error message. When I leave out the attachment the email is sent, when I include it the email never arrives, but again: no error message.

Can I even send a BlobInfo as Attachment (=Bytestring)? If not, how can I translate it?

Thanks in advance :)

```
    dataset = ""
for i in range(len(newer_table)):
  for j in range(len(newer_table[i])):
    dataset = dataset + str(newer_table[i][j]) + ','
  dataset += '\n'

file_name = files.blobstore.create(mime_type='text/comma-separated-values', _blobinfo_uploaded_filename='test')
with files.open(file_name, 'a') as f:
  f.write(dataset)
files.finalize(file_name)
blob_key = files.blobstore.get_blob_key(file_name)
blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(blob_key)
blob_reader = blobstore.BlobReader(blob_key)

#self.response.out.write(blob_reader.read())

user_address = "test@googlemail.com"
sender_address = "Test <test@googlemail.com>"
subject = "Test"
body = "Test"
mail.send_mail(sender_address, user_address, subject, body, attachments=[blob_info.filename, blob_reader.read()])
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to read the attachment in order to send it as an attachment:

```
blob_reader = blobstore.BlobReader(blob_key)
...
mail.send_mail(sender_address, user_address, subject, body, attachments=[blob_info.filename,blob_reader.read()])
```

By the way. I prefer to use Amazon SES to send mail from GAE, because the GAE mail API does not give any information about mail delivery.

Here is the code I use to send the mail:

```
    message = mail.EmailMessage(sender = 'noreply@....', subject = 'CSV')
    message.to = 'john@example.com'
    message.body = 'Download attached CSV'
    message.attachments = [blob_info.filename,blob_reader.read()]
    message.send()
```

Comment: Hey Voscausa, I get the following error:
raise ERROR_MAP[e.application_error](e.error_detail)
InvalidAttachmentTypeError: Invalid attachment type

Comment: I do not receive this error. I used this code to send a CSV. I know that not all attachment types are allowed. See this link: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/attachments

Comment: I am also using CSV - as you can see in line 1 of my code above. The file works fine and when I use print the contents of blob_reader.read() it displays the text as intended. Any other idea?

Comment: I created the CSV file using: files.blobstore.create(mime_type='text/comma-separated-values', _blobinfo_uploaded_filename='test')

Comment: I did the exact same thing - I will post the new code in the question above, including the input for the file.

Comment: I have updated my code above with my own send mail code. 
By the way: I write the CSV line by line to the blobstore, including the header. But I do not think this is the problem, when I look in your code.